# C++ Out of Subscript Range

Tags: c++, arrays, string, hex

I'm running a C++ Program that is supposed to convert string to hexadecimals. It compiles but errors out of me at runtime saying:

> Debug Assertion Failed! (Oh no!)
>
> Visual Studio2010\include\xstring
>
> Line 1440
>
> Expression: string subscript out of range

And I have no choice to abort... It seems like it converts it though up to the point of error so I'm not sure what's going on. My code is simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string hello = "Hello World";
    int i = 0;
    while(hello.length())
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)hello[i];
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What this program should do is convert each letter to hexadecimal - char by char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while condition is incorrect:

```
while(hello.length())
```

The loop never terminates and `i` becomes large (more than string length minus one) and when you access the string at that index you get runtime assertion.

Change it to:

```
while(i < hello.length())
```

Or better use iterators.

Comment: Oh wow, why would it compile then and give such a strange error message? (thanks btw)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee because compiler is not supposed to look for run-time errors. Note that if you'd had a constant or local variable in the `while` expression - you would get a warning. But a function call makes the compiler to assume data may change.

Answer (score 6):

You're not removing anything from the string and so `length()` will always return the same number which converts to `true`.

Use a for loop instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hello.length(); ++i)
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)hello[i];
}
```

Or even better, use iterators.

```
for(std::string::iterator it = hello.begin(); it != hello.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(i < hello.length())
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)hello[i];
        i++;
    }
```

Your original loop never ends. For counting indexes, I find the `for` loop syntax better suited.

Comment: @Jesse thanks:) Sometimes I feel like I'm in a competition of who shoots faster....

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the condition in while loop.

```
 while(i < hello.length())
    {
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << (unsigned int)hello[i];
        ++i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer iterators here in a for loop.

```
for (std::string::const_iterator it = hello.begin(); it != hello.end(); ++it) {
    // String processing
}
```

Or, in C++11:

```
for (char const c : hello) {
    // String processing
}
```

In general, I prefer to use iterators to access things whenever possible in C++. It's the more idiomatic way to do it, and it works for all types of STL containers. For instance, if you want to some day use a `std::deque` or `std::list`, then iterators will still work.

On another style note, I would avoid C-style casting. That is where you did `(unsigned int)`. Instead, use `static_cast<unsigned> (*it)`. This conveys your intent by only giving you casting abilities that you are actually after. A C-style cast is much more broad, but all you want here is to convert between sizes of integer types.